# Ruby on rails: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror, actioncontroller

when i try to create  it says undefined method.

```
def create
    @stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_availabilities][:stock_id])
    @stock_availability = StockAvailability.new(stock_availabilities_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @stock_availability.save 
            format.html { redirect_to stock_path(v_id: @volunteer.id), notice: "stock saved successfully" }  
        else
            @stock_availabilities = StockAvailability.where(stock_id: @stock.id).all
            format.html { render 'index' }
        end
    end
end
```

Where `stock_availabilities` belongs to `Stock` table. `foreign key` is `stock_id`.

The params Generated in log is

```
Parameters: {
    "utf8"=>"✓", 
    "authenticity_token"=>"ZWxRnGJqwLmhfosIhQ+xdLrG3HJXy1m/dHcizT+Y5+E=", 
    "stockavailability"=>{
        "qty"=>"20",
        "price"=>"2000",
        "captured_at"=>"26/8/2015"
        }, 
    "commit"=>"Save Stockavailability"
}
    Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms
```

Comment: Update your form in question.

Comment: Please post the error log.

Comment: What params do you pass into this action? What's your form and routes?

Comment: Started POST "/stockavailabilities" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-26 15:42:39 +0530
Processing by StockavailabilitiesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZWxRnGJqwLmhfosIhQ+xdLrG3HJXy1m/dHcizT+Y5+E=", "stockavailability"=>{"qty"=>"20", "price"=>"2000", "captured_at"=>"26/8/2015"}, "commit"=>"Save Stockavailability"}
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Stock without an ID):
  app/controllers/stockavailabilities_controller.rb:9:in `create'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of regenerated your issue

```
2.1.1 :003 > a=nil
 => nil 
2.1.1 :004 > a['asd']
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):4
    from /home/illu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.1.1 :005 >
```

In your case it probably
`params[:stock_availabilities]` is giving `nil` and you are trying to access the key `:stock_id` in the `nil` class.
I suggest you to pry the values at the point.

EDIT1:

After having a look at your server log it is clear that the key `stock_availabilities` you are trying to access is actually `stockavailability`

your code should be like

```
# though no :stock_id key/value is found in your server log
@stock = Stock.find(params[:stockavailability][:stock_id])
```

Answer (score 0):

try change :

```
@stock = Stock.find(params[:stock_availabilities][:stock_id])
```

to

```
@stock = Stock.find(params[:stockavailability][:stock_id])
```

Your this problem will get solved but you will get other error too. Because you are not passing `stock_id` properly in params. So try set that as well in form hidden field.

To run your code without error. You should have `stock_id` in your this param section `"stockavailability"=>{"qty"=>"20", "price"=>"2000", "captured_at"=>"26/8/2015"},`